# Invalid syntax while testing with assert Python

Tags: python, pytest

I am checking if a string starts with "4" it will classify itself as a visa card.Upon running pytest -v, returning syntax error. In my validator.py, my function looks like this:

```
def get_issuer(number: str) -> str:
    if number.startswith('4'):
        return 'Visa'
```

And I am testing this in a seperate file :

```
from card_validator.validator import get_issuer

def test_get_issuer_visa():
    assert get_issuer("4343 4212 1435 1231") == "Visa"
```

The error is

```
      def get_issuer(number: str) -> str:
E                            ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I cannot find any error. Any help on this?

EDIT :
The FULL output for pytest -v is

```
========================================================== test session starts ==========================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.15rc1, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /usr/bin/python2
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/bs-094/Dev/validator, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                                                                            

================================================================ ERRORS =================================================================
_______________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_validators.py _______________________________________________
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/python.py:403: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py:668: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:213: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
tests/test_validators.py:1: in <module>
    from card_validator.validator import get_issuer
E     File "/home/bs-094/Dev/validator/card_validator/validator.py", line 1
E       def get_issuer(number: str) -> str:
E                            ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
======================================================== 1 error in 0.12 seconds ========================================================
```

Comment: `return 'Visa` is missing a `'`. However, when you have syntax errors, the real source could be earlier in your code. Check for unclosed parentheses/brackers etc..

Comment: The unclosed parentheses is my pasting mistake. It is fine my original code, edited the post, error is still showing

Comment: Check the version of Python you are using.  Type hinting was added in Python 3.5, I believe.

Comment: please post the whole output of your `pytest -v`

Comment: @MarkTolonen the python version is 3.6.7, but the project interpreter for my current project is python 3.6. Can that be an issue?

Comment: @najjarammar added in the edited portion

Comment: Pytest says you are running `Python 2.7.15rc1`, so type hinting isn't supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script contains syntax belonging to python3. So it will only for python3.

For executing the script in python2.7(and python3 both) you can remove the colons in the function signature as below:

```
def get_issuer(number):
    if number.startswith('4'):
        return 'Visa'
```

Comment: Yes, it executes properly now. But what was wrong with declaring the arguement type and the return type? Why do I need to write compatible syntax for both 2.7 and 3.6?

Comment: You don't; you just need to ensure that pytest uses Python 3 to test Python-3-only code.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mark Tolonen mentioned in comment, typing is new in version 3.5
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Your code runs fine in 3.7.3. Upgrading to 3.5+ should fix your problem.